# Lambda - Is possible to pass the object via pipeline to another lambda (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

Is possible to send $LambdaInput into another Destination Lambda with Asynchronous invocation?

For imagination:

```
PS Lambda1: $LambdaInput = "ABC"; Write-Host $LambdaInput; $LambdaInput
|
|
----> PS Lambda2: Write-Host "This should be ABC from previous Lambda1 - $LambdaInput"
```

[image: Lamba-to-lambda]

If I hit the test from the Lambda1 it will see ABC from $LambdaInput but I can't see in logs from test button log from second Lambda2. Even in Logs Group Lambda2 has no record.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at AWS Step Functions : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/step-functions/

Tuto : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

I just realized even input from CloudWatch with constant JSON input is not being passed to second AWS Lambda in case first AWS Lambda fail.

As a workaround I hardcoded fixed input to second lambda function (which is used as a fallback and hardcoded value can be used there).

Anyway If there is possibility to pass input from CloudWatch/First lambda to second Lambda, let me know please in comments.

Thanks!

[image: lambda-chain]